# mysql get rollup value

Tags: mysql, rollup

I want to ask about mysql with rollup only get rollup value, this is my code

```
SELECT tbldept.CodeDept AS Dept,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tblemp.Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS headcount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tblemp.Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 144 AS RegHrsEst,
       CONCAT(ROUND(20), '%') AS TargetOT,
       round(SUM(CASE WHEN tblemp.Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 144 * 0.2) AS OTHrsBdgt
FROM tbldept
LEFT JOIN tblemp
    ON tbldept.CodeDept = tblemp.CodeDept AND
       tblemp.class = "DIR"
WHERE tbldept.CodeDept != 'FIN' AND
      tbldept.CodeDept != 'HRT' AND
      tbldept.CodeDept != 'ISD'
GROUP BY tbldept.CodeDept with ROLLUP;
```

result of rollup query:
[image: result of rollup query]

how can i only get the rollup values? Thanks before

Comment: Can you show us the output you want?

Comment: Hi, Tim i want to get the output like the picture before. I want to get value 
hitung, RegHrsEst,OTHrsBdgt
435, 62640, 12528
in RollUP to sum others values

Comment: You showed us the output from the _current_ query, but what is your _expected_ output?

Comment: Hi Tim, I only want the output become 
Total | hitung | RegHrsEst | TargetOT | OTHrsBdgt
Total | 435 | 62640 | 20% | 12528 |

Then the Total above want to sum other value when i input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the row of `rollup`, simply use `having`:

```
SELECT tbldept.CodeDept AS Dept,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tblemp.Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS headcount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tblemp.Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 144 AS RegHrsEst,
       CONCAT(ROUND(20), '%') AS TargetOT,
       round(SUM(CASE WHEN tblemp.Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 144 * 0.2) AS OTHrsBdgt
FROM tbldept
LEFT JOIN tblemp
    ON tbldept.CodeDept = tblemp.CodeDept AND
       tblemp.class = "DIR"
WHERE tbldept.CodeDept != 'FIN' AND
      tbldept.CodeDept != 'HRT' AND
      tbldept.CodeDept != 'ISD'
GROUP BY tbldept.CodeDept with ROLLUP
HAVING Dept IS NULL;
```

### Edit:


`having` should work, check if there are some other reasons exist or not.

Or just wrap your query with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT tbldept.CodeDept AS Dept,
           SUM(CASE WHEN tblemp.Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS headcount,
           SUM(CASE WHEN tblemp.Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 144 AS RegHrsEst,
           CONCAT(ROUND(20), '%') AS TargetOT,
           round(SUM(CASE WHEN tblemp.Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 144 * 0.2) AS OTHrsBdgt
    FROM tbldept
    LEFT JOIN tblemp
        ON tbldept.CodeDept = tblemp.CodeDept AND
           tblemp.class = "DIR"
    WHERE tbldept.CodeDept != 'FIN' AND
          tbldept.CodeDept != 'HRT' AND
          tbldept.CodeDept != 'ISD'
    GROUP BY tbldept.CodeDept with ROLLUP
) t
WHERE Dept IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Forward, The results show me blank. I just try now, any suggestion?

Comment: @MasHarjo Updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: Hi @forward, thanks is look greats answer. Sorry for my careless